# How to attach any file to APK for installing?

Tags: android-install-apk

I want attach any file or data to APK for install , and when to install that APK , my attachment file or data install on our device , how can I do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could directly add a data file to your APK (by making your file part of the assets or raw folder for example) and unpack/move/parse this file when your application starts up for the first time.

An alternative is to use an [APK expansion file](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) (only available on Google Play):

> Google Play hosts the expansion files for your application and serves
>   them to the device at no cost to you. The expansion files are saved to
>   the device's shared storage location (the SD card or USB-mountable
>   partition; also known as the "external" storage) where your app can
>   access them. On most devices, Google Play downloads the expansion
>   file(s) at the same time it downloads the APK, so your application has
>   everything it needs when the user opens it for the first time.