# Method to add predefined database into user's phone when app is installed

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there a method to add predefined SQLite database into user's phone when the app is first installed

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41250187/115145

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a few options here depending on the database size.

If it's not really big, you can **create it** on the first run, and **initialize** it from the code with the `insert` method.

If it's decent, you could [attach it to the APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640930/how-to-attach-any-file-to-apk-for-installing).

If it's really big, the previous method would make your APK weight a lot, in this case, I would suggest you **download** it on the first run.